# Solve for s that minimises $\sum_{i=0}^{n}|p_i-sr_i|$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

How can s be solved for that minimises this expression:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}|p_i-sr_i|$$

For example if $p = [7, -4, 2]$ and $r = [0.2, 0.3, -0.1]$ I observe minimum of $31/3$ is at $s = -4/0.3$.

But how can this be done in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of one dimension only, which is your case, you can easily check all null points $s=\frac{p_i}{r_i}$ and choose the one, which gives you the smallest value of your objective function.